# Executing Spice commands written in file

Tags: simulation, spice

I successfully executed ngspice commands via the command line.
When I wrote those commands to the `.net` file, and run that file via ngspice, they didn't work.

The following is my netlist file:

```
* gnetlist -g spice-sdb ./RC_filter.sch
* Spice file generated by gnetlist                      *
* spice-sdb version 4.28.2007 by SDB --                 *
R1 2 1 1MEG  
V1 2 0 DC 5V
C1 1 0 1uF  

* Set Initial conditions: Voltage on Capacitor C1 is being set to zero
.IC V(1)=0

.end
```

When that file is loaded to ngspice, and then I run the following commands:

```
tran 10m 5s
plot V(1)
```

They work perfectly.

But when those commands are written in the `.net` file, right before the `.end` line, they don't work when ngspice reads the file:

```
* ... Rest of file

.tran 10m 5s
.plot V(1)

.end
```

How can I make these commands to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the description of `.control / .endc` in the ngspice manual.

You will have to write something like:

```
.control
tran ...
plot v(1)
.endc
```